# Selenium Python click a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I can't find how to make my system click my button.
here is the code of the button (or in attachment)

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-captcha" id="invisibleCaptchaShortlink" type="submit">continue</button>
```

[image]

I've already tried this command, but it doesn't work.

```python
search = driver.find_element_by_name("invisibleCaptchaShortlink")
search.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below xpath ::

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='invisibleCaptchaShortlink'][contains(text(),'continue')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id("invisibleCaptchaShortlink")
```

You are trying to search element with incorrect strategy use above xpath to locate your element `find_element_by_name` not valid instead of that you should use `find_element_by_id`

Comment: @antoinerzad1: Can you please accept the answer if your issue is resolved ?